# Update data-attribute value on active class change

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Trying to create a function that console.logs the data-attribute associated with an .active class each time the .active class changes elements.

So far I can only get the initial data attribute value of the first element's .active class. Calling the function after the .active class has changed elements produces the same results as initially calling the function.

```
// Variables
var activeItem = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

// Get the Data-Targ value from the .active_class
 var  active_href = function() {
    for (i = 0; i < activeItem.length; ++i) {
      var reports = activeItem[i].dataset.targ;
      console.log('data-targ of .active is: ' + reports);
    }
  };
```

In reply to comments, this is how I am initially attaching the .active class. 
It is being attached to the first child of the parent container.
(essentially, the first li of the ul it is contained in)

```
  var first_child = ul.children[0];
  var active = first_child.classList.add('active');
```

So, the active_href isn't calling the dynamically updated .active class placement along the ul > li chain that happens through Next and Previous buttons containing the event handlers that add and remove the active class.

Comment: *"Calling the function after the .active class has changed elements"*: could you share the code that these calls?

Comment: Can't you just move the `activeItem` variable declaration into the `active_href` function?

Comment: @DavidDomain yes you can!  Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Comment: @newneub - Sure, no problem. ;)

Comment: @newneub additionally, -why are you skipping your first `activeItem` from the collection, that is: why are you using ++I in your iterator?